# putting node linked list in alphabetical order

Tags: c++

I need to make it so the user can put in words until they hit enter 'xxx'. this part is already done, but then i need the list to always be in alphabetical order. I cant figure out how to do this part. I have to make it in alphabetical order in the function that adds a new node, not the function that prints the nodes to the screen. this is because it is for a class and is required.

Node header file:

```
struct Node
{
    string       word;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

The function prototype header file:

```
Node *add_node(Node *list, const string &s);
Node *del_node(Node *list, const string &s);

void deallocate(Node *list);
void print(Node *list);
```

The code that gets compiled:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <iomanip>
#include    <string>
using namespace std;

#include    "Node.h"
#include    "funcs.h"

int main()
{
    struct Node *list = 0;      // list is a pointer to struct Node

    cout << "please enter a few words (xxx to terminate list):\n";

    string s;                   // s is a string object

    while (cin >> s)           // read a string into s
    {
        if (s == "xxx")
        {
            break;              // terminate loop when string is equal to         "xxx"
        }
        // add s to list in alphabetical order
        list = add_node(list, s);

        cout << "\nlist:\n";
        print(list);
        cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << "\nhere is the list:\n";
    print(list);
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "please enter word words to delete from the list (xxx to    terminate):\n";
        while (cin >> s)
        {
            if (s == "xxx")
            {
                break;              // terminate loop when string is equal to "xxx"
            }
            // delete first node containing string s
            //list = del_node(list, s);

            cout << "\nlist:\n";
            print(list);
            cout << '\n';
        }

    cout << "\nthe final list:\n";
    print(list);
    cout << '\n';
    // deallocate the linked list
    cout << "\ndeallocating the list:\n";
    deallocate(list);

    cout << "\nall done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The code with the functions:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <iomanip>
#include    <string>
using namespace std;

#include    "Node.h"


Node *add_node(Node *list, const string &s)
{
    struct Node *n = new struct Node;
    n->word = s;            // copy string s to word
    n->next = list;

    // add node n to the list 
    // the list should always be in ascending alphabetical order

    list = n;

    return list;            // returning pointer to beginning of the list
}


Node *del_node(Node *list, const string &s)
{
    // delete node in the list that contains s
    // the list should always be in ascending alphabetical order

    // if s does not appear in the list, there is nothing to do
    // if s appears multiple times in the list, delete the first occurrence
    Node *lastp = 0;
    Node *p = list;
    for (; p; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->word == s)
        {
            lastp->next = p->next;
            delete p;
            break;
        }
        lastp = p;
    } 


    return list;            // returning pointer to beginning of the list
}


void deallocate(Node *list)
{
    for (struct Node *p = list; p;)
    {
        struct Node *tmp = p;   // remember current pointer

        p = p->next;            // advance p to the next node

        delete tmp;             // deallocate tmp

        // OK to print pointers tmp and p
        cout << "deallocated\t" << tmp << "\tnext is\t" << p << '\n';
    }
}


void print(Node *list)
{
    for (struct Node *p = list; p; p = p->next)
    {
        cout << p << '\t' << setw(8) << p->word
            << '\t' << "next:" << '\t' << p->next << '\n';
    }
}
```

All the code probably isnt required to answer the question but i figured i'd include it.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: i thought you could just use < to see what comes first in the alphabet but i dont get how to sort the list when your not printing it because the assignment requires me to sort it in the add_node function like i said

Comment: You're not supposed to sort it, just find the correct location to insert the new node. Pen and paper are very useful tools when working with pointers.

Comment: Drawing pictures is very useful when working with linked lists.  Pencils are good because you can erase the lines when links need to be erased.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews  Your and the preceeding comments are very confusing because it is not clear now what to use whether a pen or a pencil.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow lmao

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, use whichever you prefer, pen or pencils, in your drawings.

Comment: @StarPilot Does the C++ Standard allow to use either one?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, the C++ Standard does not go into that level of detail concerning design drawings or developer notes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function add_node shown in the demonstrative program below. Take into account that you need to define one more function that will free all allocated memory in the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Node
{
    std::string word;
    struct Node *next;
};

Node *add_node( struct Node *list, const std::string &s )
{
    struct Node *prev = nullptr;
    struct Node *current = list;

    while ( current && !( s < current->word ) )
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if ( prev == nullptr )
    {
        list = new Node { s, list };
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = new Node { s, prev->next };
    }

    return list;
}

void print_list( const struct Node *list )
{
    for ( ; list != nullptr; list = list->next ) std::cout << list->word << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *list = nullptr;

    // for ( const std::string &s : { "B", "X", "A", "C", "F", "G" } )
    for ( const char *s : { "B", "X", "A", "C", "F", "G" } )
    {
        list = add_node( list, s );
    }

    print_list( list );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
A B C F G X
```